# Shortening list of arguments to some kind of a variadic function

Tags: c#

If you look at `ImportAndPreload` method, it looks bad because:

*MovingAverageConvergenceDivergence*, *StochasticRSI*, *RelativeStrengthIndex* and *ExponentialMovingAverage*. They are all indicators, they all inherit from `IndicatorBase`. What would happen if I wanted to pass a few more indicators? There would be 10 indicators passed by arguments, which is annoying and it's against S.O.L.I.D. Is there a way to make that method like a variadic function in C++ and pass infinite amount of indicators. By the way, as you can see below, IndicatorBase is generic, which prevents `params IndicatorBase<???>[] args`.

For example: `ImportAndPreload(symbol, interval, macd, stoch, rsi, ema, ...)`

I'm also open for other ideas.

````
MovingAverageConvergenceDivergence macd = new MovingAverageConvergenceDivergence(12, 26, 100);
StochasticRSI stoch = new StochasticRSI(14, 9, 3, 3);
RelativeStrengthIndex rsi = new RelativeStrengthIndex(20);
ExponentialMovingAverage ema = new ExponentialMovingAverage(20);

ImportAndPreload(symbol, interval, macd, stoch, rsi, ema);

// Abstract base class for all indicators:
public abstract class IndicatorBase<TInput, TOutput>
    where TInput: struct
    where TOutput : struct
{
    public abstract TOutput ComputeNextValue(TInput input);
    public abstract void Reset();
}

private void ImportAndPreload(string symbol, KlineInterval interval, MovingAverageConvergenceDivergence macd, StochasticRSI stoch, RelativeStrengthIndex rsi, ExponentialMovingAverage ema)
{
    // Import candles
    List<BinanceKline> candles = Client.GetKlines(symbol, interval, limit: 1000).Data.SkipLast(1).ToList();

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        List<BinanceKline> moreCandles2 = Client.GetKlines(symbol, interval, startTime: null, endTime: candles.First().OpenTime, limit: 1000).Data.SkipLast(1).ToList();
        candles.InsertRange(0, moreCandles2);
    }

    // Workaround in case it gets more bigger time to import candles
    List<BinanceKline> moreCandles = Client.GetKlines(symbol, interval, limit: 2).Data.SkipLast(1).ToList();
    candles.AddRange(moreCandles.ExceptUsingJsonCompare(candles));

    // Preload indicators
    for (int i = 0; i < candles.Count; i++)
    {
        macd.ComputeNextValue(candles[i].Close);
        stoch.ComputeNextValue(candles[i].Close);
        rsi.ComputeNextValue(candles[i].Close);
        ema.ComputeNextValue(candles[i].Close);
    }
}
```
````

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This will depend on whether or not all of the indicators you're interested in passing have the same generic type arguments. If they do then iSR5's solution is the simplest.

If not then you'll need a more complicated solution. On one hand I notice that you're not using any of the outputs of `ComputeNextValue`; you're only providing inputs to the indicators. Then one possible solution would be to define an interface with the void counterpart of `ComputeNextValue` which only takes an input and produces no output:

```
public abstract class IndicatorBase<TInput, TOutput> : IIndicatorBase<TInput>
    where TInput : struct
    where TOutput : struct
{
    public abstract TOutput ComputeNextValue(TInput input);
    public abstract void Reset();

    void IIndicatorBase<TInput>.ComputeNextValue(TInput input) =>
         ((IndicatorBase<TInput, TOutput>)this).ComputeNextValue(input);
}

public interface IIndicatorBase<TInput>
    where TInput: struct
{
    void ComputeNextValue(TInput input);
}
```

Then `ImportAndPreload` can become this: (I'm not sure what `BinanceKline` is, but the input type you're supplying to each indicator is the type of `BinanceKline.Close`, so that'd be the generic type argument for `IIndicatorBase`)

```
private void ImportAndPreload(string symbol, KlineInterval interval, params IIndicatorBase<TypeOfBinanceKlineDotClose>[] indicators)
{
    ...

    // Preload indicators
    for (int i = 0; i < candles.Count; i++)
    {
        foreach (var indicator in indicators)
        {
            indicator.ComputeNextValue(candles[i].Close);
        }
    }
}

...

ImportAndPreload(symbol, interval, macd, stoch, rsi, ema);
```

This will support any indicator whose input is the type of `BinanceKline.Close`.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks a lot, that's what I wanted!

Answer (score 4):

The simplest solution would be using `params`.

```
private void ImportAndPreload<TInput, TOutput>(params IndicatorBase<TInput, TOutput>[] foos) { ... }
```

if you want something more managed, you can use `IEnumerable<IndicatorBase<TInput, TOutput>>` which would makes uses any type of collections. I would prefer using `IEnumereble` over `params` in this case, because you would store all indicators into a collection, which would be easier to handle, move (if needed) or even modify.

Comment: Isn't that only if you have same `TInput` and `TOutput` for all indicators you will pass to params? For example: `public class MovingAverageConvergenceDivergence : IndicatorBase<decimal, (decimal Signal, decimal MACD, decimal Histogram)>`  `public class ExponentialMovingAverage : IndicatorBase<decimal, decimal>`. They have different TInput/TOutput.

Comment: @nop since its `TInput` and `TOutput` are different, then it won't be possible to use this approach. Use Jeff 's method in this case.

Comment: yup, thanks for your answer too!